# I get an invalid token?

Tags: symfony, jwt

I work under a Docker project. Symfony 5.

- the registration goes well, I have the user registered in the database
- the connection goes well, I get the token
- there is a record line in the auth table with the token during the connection
- on the other hand the access to a protected route it indicates me that the token is not valid

GET http://localhost:8003/api/users/13
Authorization Bearer ey..............................................................

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid JWT Token"
}
```

security.yml

```yaml
security:
  encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: bcrypt

  providers:
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email

  firewalls:
    refresh:
      pattern: ^/api/token/refresh
      stateless: true
      anonymous: true

    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    doc:
      pattern: ^/doc
      security: false

    login:
      pattern: ^/api/login
      stateless: true
      anonymous: true
      json_login:
        username_path: email
        check_path: /api/login/token
        success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
        failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    user_register:
      pattern: ^/api/user/register
      stateless: true
      anonymous: true

    main:
      pattern: ^/api
      stateless: true
      anonymous: false
      provider: app_user_provider
      guard:
        authenticators:
          - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/token/refresh, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/user/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml

```yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
  private_key_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/%env(JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH)%"
  public_key_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/%env(JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH)%"
  pass_phrase: "%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%"

  token_ttl: 3600 # token TTL in seconds, defaults to 1 hour
  user_identity_field: email 
  clock_skew: 0

  encoder:
    service: lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder.lcobucci

    signature_algorithm: RS256

  token_extractors:
    authorization_header:
      enabled: true
      prefix: Bearer
      name: Authorization

    cookie:
      enabled: false
      name: BEARER

    query_parameter:
      enabled: false
      name: bearer
```

I have created the 2 certificates with the right passphrase :

.env

```yaml
...
JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=f8bfe4494b7cf3032d642a3e72dcac53
```

/config/jwt/private.pem
/config/jwt/public.pem

\vendor\Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Guard\JWTTokenAuthenticator.php

```php
public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $tokenExtractor = $this->getTokenExtractor();

        if (!$tokenExtractor instanceof TokenExtractorInterface) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Method "%s::getTokenExtractor()" must return an instance of "%s".', __CLASS__, TokenExtractorInterface::class));
        }

        if (false === ($jsonWebToken = $tokenExtractor->extract($request))) {
            return;
        }

        $preAuthToken = new PreAuthenticationJWTUserToken($jsonWebToken);

        try {
            dump($preAuthToken);                                // --------------
            dump($this->jwtManager->decode($preAuthToken));     //    ERROR HERE
                                                                // -------------- 
            if (!$payload = $this->jwtManager->decode($preAuthToken)) {
                throw new InvalidTokenException('Invalid JWT Token');
            }

            $preAuthToken->setPayload($payload);
        } catch (JWTDecodeFailureException $e) {
            if (JWTDecodeFailureException::EXPIRED_TOKEN === $e->getReason()) {
                $expiredTokenException = new ExpiredTokenException();
                $expiredTokenException->setToken($preAuthToken);
                throw $expiredTokenException;
            }
            throw new InvalidTokenException('Invalid JWT Token', 0, $e);
        }

        return $preAuthToken;
    }
```

dump($preAuthToken);

```json
JWTTokenAuthenticator.php on line 106:
Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Authentication\Token\PreAuthenticationJWTUserToken {#598
  -rawToken: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOjIyLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InRvdG8xMUB0b3RvLmZyIiwiaWF0IjoxNjIyMDI3NzQ4fQ.COr_fuXAH8iq3Ecr8mJVIVVdLI6H5zv7419gvQwLy6Q"
  -payload: null
  -credentials: null
  -guardProviderKey: null
  -user: null
  -roleNames: []
  -authenticated: false
  -attributes: []
}
```

- it's the right token passed in the request

an error occurs on this line:  `$this->jwtManager->decode($preAuthToken)`
and triggers:  `new InvalidTokenException('Invalid JWT Token', 0, $e);`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Having seen similar problems just some days ago, I can recommend to start XDebug to step through the code - it's pretty well structured :)

Comment: I can't find the problem :(

Comment: Are your env variables right? You seem to be adding `kernel.project_dir` in two places (although the variable names you show are different).

Comment: So, what have you tried to resolve the problem? Started the debugger?

Comment: I modified the .env, I even tried with hard values.
I can't see anything with the debugger

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem? Does mgs's hint help, that `JWT_SECRET_KEY` already contains the directory path, and your service configuration adds this path a second time?

Comment: I put %env on all 3 and still the same :(  secret_key: "%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%"

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? Does the debugger help you to see which paths are used?

Comment: Please share more details. It's good that you've found the line throwing the error. Please go on debugging - as a hint: this is way easier using XDebug, as you don't have to modfy the source code

Comment: It's not *entirely* clear to me if `decode` throws directly or just returns `null`, but since you mention `$e`, that should be a wrapped exception and hopefully give you [more information](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Exception/JWTDecodeFailureException.php), a stacktrace to follow or you could go [straight to the source](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Encoder/LcobucciJWTEncoder.php). Are your clocks synchronized?

Comment: Guys, please be careful posting tokens. They contain sensitive data, such as email addresses or group names, from which you can get customer names and customer relation information. This in conjunction with the question leads to background knowledge very valuable for hackers.

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using of LexikJWTAuthentication ? I guess the latest with symfony 5, you should use param **public_key** instead of **public_key_path** : https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-configuration-reference.md